# How to reduce HTML to a single line with no whitespace via Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob, minify

I'm trying to minify HTML with Gulp to remove all line breaks and white space so the entire code content resides on one line only and with no redundant whitespace like tabs and spaces, including in embedded JavaScript and CSS.

I've tried [gulp-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify), but I do not see the output or compression options for that, which leaves me cross-eyed. I thought that was one of the common functions of minification. [This beautifier/minifier](https://beautifytools.com/html-beautifier.php) does precisely what I need via its minify button, but I need that functionality via Gulp.

Ok I'm going insane. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into this https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin. gulp-minify is meant to minify javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const minHTML = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.task("htmlMin", function () {
  return (
    gulp
      .src("./*.html")
      .pipe(minHTML({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
  );
});

exports.default = gulp.series("htmlMin");
```

And run it with just `gulp` at the command line.

Using [gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin) as suggested by @Cully in the comments, and I already had.

```
  ~/replace ==>  gulp
[01:23:36] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Test Bed\replace\gulpfile.js
[01:23:36] Starting 'default'...
[01:23:36] Starting 'htmlMin'...
[01:23:36] Finished 'htmlMin' after 127 ms
[01:23:36] Finished 'default' after 132 ms
```

Comment: Hm, it's not reducing my code to a single line...

Comment: It is for me.  Each html file is down to one line. Is the `htmlMin` task running?  Any errors printed?  If you delete your `dist` folder and then run `gulp`, is the `dist` folder created with the files in it?

Comment: No errors. I delete the file/directory. The file populates into dist, so I know it's running...

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: W11, but that shouldn't make any difference to this.

Comment: I was mislead. It is working!